# django, slickgrid, and json loading

Tags: ajax, django, json, slickgrid

I'm trying to learn how to use a javascript based editable grid system with Django. It's pretty confusing for someone brand new to javascript as well as ajax and json handling within django.

I've been looking at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) because it seems to do what I want it too, mainly editable fields that are quickly sorted, filtered, and searched. I'd be open to other packages with similar functionality.

I'm stuck on populating the grid with my json. I'm not even sure it's the js or the format of the json which is the problem.

Here is a simplified example.

I'm 'serving' the json with the following view:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def json_testing(request):
    json = serialize("json", FooBar.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
# urls.py is configured to access this at /json_testing/
```

Here's the output of the json at www.example.com/json_testing/ :

```
[
  - {
        pk: 1
        model: "myapp.foobar"
      - fields: {
            foo: "test"
            bar: "test"
        }
    },
  - {
        pk: 2
        model: "myapp.foobar"
      - fields: {
            foo: "test2"
            bar: "test2"
        }
    }
]
```

And here's my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>SlickGrid example 1: Basic grid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div width="100%">
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;display:none;"></div>
</div>
<script src="/static/SlickGrid/lib/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="/static/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var grid;

var columns = [
    {id:"foo", name:"Foo", field:"foo"},
    {id:"bar", name:"Bar", field:"bar"}
];

var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};

$(function() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0, i < 50; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            foo: "foo_" + i,
            bar: "bar_" + i,
        };
    }

// I want to replace the loop to generate code above with json
// I think something along the lines of this
//    $.get_json('/json_testing/')

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

    $("#myGrid").show();
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I know the answer to this is probably pretty basic. Maybe it's so basic that's why it's hard to find an existing answer on the web.

Every method for loading the json that I've tried from other answers, blogs, etc has resulted in a blank grid being rendered. **What do I need to do to get my json loaded?**

Comment: Note: in Nov 2023, https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid (original) points to https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid ("most active fork")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying slickgrid and dojo & dojango, I ended up finally finding success with JQuery and [django-jqgrid](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid) (although not without frustration).

While this is not an answer to the question, it was a solution to this problem for me. I say solution, not workaround, because I didn't need slickgrid, just any editable grid.

Comment: Note: in Nov 2023, django-jqgrid was last updated Jan 2017.

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of trouble with Ajax + slickgrid until I started using a slickgrid fork that had been updated to newer jQuery versions (i.e. using the newer ajax calls) and had slightly better docs for using ajax.

See my answer to another question here: [Simple jQuery SlickGrid JSON example or documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984167/simple-jquery-slickgrid-json-example-or-documentation/5709886#5709886)

Comment: I'll have to check it out. guess that means a lot of find and replace again for media urls haha. I got [dojango](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/) running too, but it looks like it'll need some tweaking to have editable grids.