# Populating slickgrid(JS) with PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, slickgrid

I have this huge slickgrid that users can fill with data. once filled in the data is sent to the server-side with AJAX and then to the database with PHP. then I get the data out of the database and put it inside a PHP array. Now how do I populate the slickgrid with that array data. I cant seem to find the solution to this. because How to I get that php array inside the javascript slickgrid file.

javascript slickgrid for information:

```
 <script type ='text/javascript'>
  var gridArray;
  var editedRows = []
  
  function CreateColumns() {
      var columns = [
        {id: "hours", name: "uren", field: "hours"},
        {id: "Total_inspection", name: "totaal inspectie", field: "Total_inspection", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer},
        {id: "Per_hour_inspection", name: "Per uur", field: "Per_hour_inspection"},
        {id: "Total_losses", name: "Totaal uitstoot", field: "Total_losses",editor: Slick.Editors.Integer},
        {id: "Per_hour_losses", name: "Per uur", field: "Per_hour_losses"},
        {id: "%_spil", name: "% Spil", field: "%_spil"},
        {id: "%_cumul", name: "% Cumul", field: "%_cumul"},
        {id: "Operator", name: "Operator", field: "Operator",editor: Slick.Editors.Text},
        {id: "SKU", name: "SKU", field: "SKU",editor: Slick.Editors.Text},
        {id: "End_SKU", name: "Tellerstand einde SKU", field: "End_SKU"},
        {id: "Batch", name: "Batch", field: "Batch"}
      ];
    return columns;
  }

 function CreateOptions() {
    var options = {
    editable: true,
      enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false,
    autoEdit :false
    };
    return options;
  }
  
  var data = [];
  function CreateData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        hours: 6+i+"U",
      };
    }
    
  return data;
  }
  
 console.log(data)

  function CreateGrid(elementId) {
    if (!gridArray) { gridArray = []; }
    
    var data = CreateData();
  //editedRows.push(data)
  var grid = new Slick.Grid("#" + elementId,data, CreateColumns(), CreateOptions());


  gridArray[length] = grid;
//todo tets localstorage
  var columnidx = data[0].Total_inspection
  var columnidx2 = data[0].Total_losses
  var calculation = columnidx2/columnidx
  var columnidx3 = data[0].Per_hour_inspection
  //push(calculation)
  var columnid = data[columnidx] 
    //console.log(calculation,columnidx3)

    grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e,args) { 
                 //console.log('arguments',args.item);
               
                editedRows.push(args.item)
                 console.log('arrayrows',editedRows)
             });

  }

console.log(editedRows)
  $('#Savebtn').click(function () {
            console.log(editedRows);
            
            //var UpdatedRows = JSON.stringify(editedRows);
            //console.log(UpdatedRows);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "request.php",// changed
                data: {arrayOfValues: editedRows},
                success: function (data) {
                    // here comes your response after calling the server
                    alert('Suceeded');
                    alert(data)
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error : " + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP looks like this :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM  kicdata");
//$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$return_data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $return_data[]= $row;
}
var_dump($return_data);
```

UPDATE: the use of ajax solved the part to send the server-side array to the client-side.

Comment: have u tried encoding the data into a json and using that data? php has a function json_encode($data) which can be used.

Comment: I Just don't get how do I Access that php Array in JS my 2 files are separate one php file and one js file both separate files ?

Comment: PHP is backend server side while SlickGrid is totally frontend side, you need to send your data as JSON, for example this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984167/simple-jquery-slickgrid-json-example-or-documentation) tells you how.

Comment: @ghiscoding in the meantime I got it working but how do populate the grid with that server data so I already have the array with data on the client-side from the server-side. but as you can see I already have a Grid how to i 'Overwrite' it with the new data from the server-side ?

Comment: That is not your original question, if you found how to do it then I suggest you update your question or answer your own question to avoid having others to spend time answering your question which you already figured out... to answer the 2nd question (not in your original question) `grid.setData(newData)`, you should look at the source code (that is what I did), on this [line](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L5847)

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks for the suggestion. the grid is coming thru but the data not. thanks for the help anyways

Comment: @pinkfloyt you need to understand what events or data changes happen within the slickgrid as you change or overwrite data on the slickgrid. Then create an ajax and update the server with certain data only (which you have changed, data may contain the id, column or what data is being entered).